# Trying to change an elements opacity on click using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, function, onclick

So far I've been able to turn the elements opacity on. But haven't managed to turn it off on a click.

Sorry if my terminology is off, i'm just starting out. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$('.link-left').on('click', function () {
$('.about').css('opacity', '1',1000);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about toggling a class and use `opacity` there?

```js
const $about = $('.about'), $link = $('.link-left');
$link.on('click', ()=> $about.toggleClass('show'));
```

```css
.about {
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
  opacity: 0;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="link-left">toggle</button>
<div class="about">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</div>
```

If you only want jQuery, maybe something like this will do the trick:

```js
const $about = $('.about'), $link = $('.link-left');
let showing = false;
$link.on('click', ()=> {
  showing = !showing;
  $about.css('opacity',Number(showing));
});
```

```css
.about {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="link-left">toggle</button>
<div class="about">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea was good, you just needed to get the syntax right

```
$('.link-left').on('click', function () {
  $('.about').css('opacity', 0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fadeToggle(1000)` the number inside the parenthesis is the fade speed in millisenconds. The good thing about this jQuery method is that it makes the div disappear completely. That's why I added the attribute `cursor:pointer;` to the `.about` class, so you can see that after it fades away is not there anymore, in opposite case to opacity, which makes the div not visible but is still there.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.link-left').on('click', () => $(".about").fadeToggle(1000))
})
```

```css
.about {
  cursor:pointer;
  background-color:blue;
  color:white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="link-left">toggle</button>
<p>
<div class="about" style="display:none;">Im here bitches!</div>
```

### Note

`$('.link-left').on('click', () => $(".about").fadeToggle(1000))` this is the same as:

```
$('.link-left').on('click', function(){
 $(".about").fadeToggle(1000)
})
```

It's a cleaner approach that I like.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the function on click then may be something like this would help you.

```
$(".link-left").click(function(){
$(".about").css("opacity", 1);
});
```

This worked for me. However, many times our browser doesn't pick up the jQuery syntax because we need to include the CDN of jQuery in the header script. Make sure that you have done that.